# pycharm error running, cannot find runner on docker debug

Tags: docker, debugging, pycharm

I am trying to debug docker image on pycharm, but getting this kind error.

```
error running 'docker_image_config' 
cannot find runner for 'docker_image_config'
```

When I run **docker_image_config**, it runs well, but when I try to debug, it shows the above error.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem ?

Please help me!!!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I am having same issue with phpstorm.